# matplotlib: scatter plot with legend as string of class

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Plotting scatter distribution for binary classification `['cat', 'dog']`:

```
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, n_redundant=0,
    n_clusters_per_class=1, weights=[0.9], flip_y=0, random_state=1,)

counter = Counter(y)

for label, _ in counter.items():
    row_ix = np.where(y == label)[0]
    plt.scatter(X[row_ix, 0], X[row_ix, 1], label=label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

I wanted to replace `0`, `1` legend with `cat`, `dog`. Here I go:

```
for label, _ in counter.items():
    row_ix = np.where(y == label)[0]
    plt.scatter(X[row_ix, 0], X[row_ix, 1], label=['cat', 'dog'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: `plt.scatter(X[row_ix, 0], X[row_ix, 1], label='cat' if label==0 else 'dog')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the value of the legend's label in every iteration of the `for` loop, one possibility being the use of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for item, animal in zip(counter.items(), ['cat', 'dog']):
    row_ix = np.where(y == item[0])[0]
    plt.scatter(X[row_ix, 0], X[row_ix, 1], label=animal)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```